# REDIS/SPRING-BOOT: Have object (in my case SseEmitter) as part of object that is stored in Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, eventemitter

I am having an issue, I am trying to store an object of UserSSE (my custom class) in my Redis. This object contains to data inside, an id, and a SseEmitter. I really need that SseEmitter to be stored for later use, and I chose Redis since it will be a quick way to get it and dispose of it since I will only use such object few times and for a short amount of time.

If I change the SseEmitter for a String (which I only did for debug purposes) it all runs fine and well, so the problem is for sure on storing such SseEmitter as part of my UserSSE in Redis.

Here is the error I am given:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: com.springbootsecurityjwt.demo.intercommunication.serverSideEvents.redis.entity.UserSSE; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6802715826521416298, local class serialVersionUID = -2205037872029018309] with root cause

java.io.InvalidClassException: com.springbootsecurityjwt.demo.intercommunication.serverSideEvents.redis.entity.UserSSE; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6802715826521416298, local class serialVersionUID = -2205037872029018309
```

And here is the UserSSE Class:

```
@RedisHash("UserSSE")
public class UserSSE implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private SseEmitter sseEmitter;
       
     *** Getters Setters and Constructors Skipped

    }
```

Here is the GET endpoint that adds to add the object to Redis:

```
@Autowired
    private UserSSEDao userSSEDao;

    @GetMapping("/memory")
    public UserSSE handle(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsImpl userDetailsIml) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        try{
            UserSSE userSSE = new UserSSE();
            userSSE.setId(userDetailsIml.getId());
            userSSE.setSseEmitter(emitter);
            userSSEDao.save(userSSE);
            return userSSE;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userSSEDao.findUserSSEById(userDetailsIml.getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try create pojo that extends SseEmitter and implements Serializable interface

```
public class CustomSSE extends SseEmitter implements Serializable {
    // super class override
}
```